# If contains help text display on view?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently I have a div class by default displaying none, however I want the value from help text if it contains the help text. I think something like if value from dropdown contains help text display.show

Below is my div

```
<div class="alert alert-info col-md-12" id="ProfHelpAlert" role="alert" style="display:none">
    <i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <strong class="notification" id="ProfHelp"></strong>
</div>
```

This is my JavaScript

```
$('#profession').on('change', function (e) { //Gets the ID of profession drop down list
    var selectedVal = $(this).val(); //Variable selectedVal this . value
    $.ajax({ //Ajax declared
        type: 'GET', //Its a get
        url: "@Url.Action("GetenquiryTypes", "UnauthEnquiry")", //It goes to the enquiry controller method GetenquiryTypes
        dataType: 'json', //Datatypes JSON
        data: { SelectedProfession: selectedVal }, //data is SelectedProfession: selectedVal
        success: function (json) { //Jquery Parse Json data from server on ajax success
            $('#ProfHelp').html(json.helptext);

            var targetDropdown = $('#enquirytype') //Var targetDropDropdown goes to dropdown ID enquiry type
            targetDropdown.empty(); //target empty dropdown
            $("<option />", {
                val: "",
                text: "Please select enquiry type" //Select enquiry type
            }).appendTo(targetDropdown); //add to the target dd
            if (json.enquiryTypes.length > 0) { //if JASON data from server greater then 0
                for (var EnquiryType in json.enquiryTypes) { //go through each EnquiryType in JSON
                    $("<option />", {
                        val: json.enquiryTypes[EnquiryType].EnquiryId, //mapping
                        text: json.enquiryTypes[EnquiryType].Enquiryname //mapping
                    }).appendTo(targetDropdown); //add to drop down

                };
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you saying you want to show your help message when the ajax method succeeds? If so, is this what you are looking for?

```
success: function(json) {
  //... add to end of method
 if(json.helptext) {
   $('#ProfHelpAlert').show();
 }
}
```

Do you need a comparison to the value of the select?

```
success: function(json) {
  //... add to end of method
 if(json.helptext == selectedVal) {
   $('#ProfHelpAlert').show();
 }
}
```

Comment: Im trying to say if help text exists for the value in the drop down then show @matthew levy

Comment: Where in your code do you know that "help text exists"? Do you mean the "text" parameter in the option declarations?

Comment: if (json.helptext != undefined && json.helptext != '')
                            {
                            $('#ProfHelp').html(json.helptext).show(); ///////
                        }
this aint working

Comment: #ProfHelp is nested in #ProfHelpAlert, which is the element that is hidden. 

$('#ProfHelp').html(json.helptext); 
$('#ProfHelpAlert').show();

Comment: Consider showing the JSON here. json.helptext makes less sense to me than something like json.[enquirytype].helptext. (alongside the name and id)